# Moving MKCircle on MKMapview and dragging MKMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uipangesturerecognizer, mkoverlay

I have a MKCircle on MKMapView. It is user-draggable, but if the user drags the area outside the circle, the map should be moving instead.

```
- (IBAction)createPanGestureRecognizer:(id)sender
{
    _mapView.scrollEnabled=NO;
    _panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToPanGesture:)];
    [_mapView addGestureRecognizer:_panRecognizer];
}

-(void)respondToPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    static CGPoint originalPoint;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:_mapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D tapCoordinate = [_mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];

        CLLocation *tapLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:tapCoordinate.latitude longitude:tapCoordinate.longitude];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D originalCoordinate = [_circle coordinate];
        CLLocation *originalLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:originalCoordinate.latitude longitude:originalCoordinate.longitude];

        if ([tapLocation distanceFromLocation:originalLocation] > [_circle radius]) {
            _mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;
            _isAllowedToMove=NO;
        }
        else if ([tapLocation distanceFromLocation:originalLocation] < [_circle radius]) {
            originalPoint = [_mapView convertCoordinate:originalCoordinate toPointToView:sender.view];
            _isAllowedToMove=YES;
        }
    }

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        if (_isAllowedToMove)
        {
            CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:sender.view];
            CGPoint newPoint    = CGPointMake(originalPoint.x + translation.x, originalPoint.y + translation.y);

            CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = [_mapView convertPoint:newPoint toCoordinateFromView:sender.view];

            MKCircle *circle2 = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:newCoordinate radius:[_circle radius]];
            [_mapView addOverlay:circle2];
            [_mapView removeOverlay:_circle];
            _circle = circle2;
        }
    }

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
        _mapView.scrollEnabled=NO;
        _isAllowedToMove=NO;
    }
}
```

Dragging the circle works fine, but when trying to drag the map, it stays still.
My assumption is that

```
_mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;
```

makes the map draggable, but it needs another drag gesture to be started.
How to accomplish this without losing the ability to move the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it so that the map can be dragged if the user starts dragging outside the circle (and to *not* drag the map if the user starts dragging *inside* the circle), don't disable `scrollEnabled` from the beginning -- leave it on (until dragging *starts* and we can decide whether to disable or not).

In order to leave `scrollEnabled` on initially (ie. let the map do its own panning) *and* to add our own gesture recognizer, we'll need to implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` and return `YES`.

The updated `createPanGestureRecognizer:` would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)createPanGestureRecognizer:(id)sender
{
    //_mapView.scrollEnabled=NO;  // <-- do NOT disable scrolling here
    _panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToPanGesture:)];
    _panRecognizer.delegate = self;  // <-- to implement shouldRecognize
    [_mapView addGestureRecognizer:_panRecognizer];
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Then in our gesture handler, when the gesture *begins*, enable or disable `scrollEnabled` based on where the pan starts (outside or inside the circle):

```
if ([tapLocation distanceFromLocation:originalLocation] > [_circle radius]) {
    _mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    _isAllowedToMove=NO;
}
else //if ([tapLocation distanceFromLocation:originalLocation] < [_circle radius]) {
//NOTE: It's not really necessary to check if distance is less than radius
//      in the ELSE part since in the IF we checked if it's greater-than.
//      If we get to the ELSE, we know distance is <= radius.
//      Unless for some reason you want to handle the case where
//      distance exactly equals radius differently but this is unlikely.
{
    originalPoint = [_mapView convertCoordinate:originalCoordinate toPointToView:sender.view];
    _mapView.scrollEnabled=NO;  // <-- disable scrolling HERE
    _isAllowedToMove=YES;
}
```

Finally, always re-enable `scrollEnabled` when a gesture ends (just in case).
When the next gesture starts, it will be re-disabled if necessary:

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
    _mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;  // <-- enable instead of disable
    _isAllowedToMove=NO;
}
```

Note that if the user is allowed to call `createPanGestureRecognizer:` multiple times, you should probably move the creation and addition of the recognizer somewhere else (`viewDidLoad` maybe) otherwise multiple instances will get added to the map.

Alternatively, change the button to a toggle so that if "move" mode is ON, it removes the gesture recognizer from the map instead of creating and adding it.

Comment: Thanks. I was implementing `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` and twisting the code tens of ways, but I forgot something as simple as `_panRecognizer.delegate = self`; In case someone wants to use the code, don't forget to add `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` to the end of the @interface line. To add or remove the gesture recognizer I use the toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer using **swift 4**

Includes some changes:
`panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1` to avoid detecting pinch to zoom as pan gesture
Screen points used for active area where pan gesture can be started.

```
private func addPanGestureRecognizer(to map: MKMapView) {
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToPanGesture(_:)))
    panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    panGesture.delegate = self
    map.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

@objc private func respondToPanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let map = self.map else {
        return
    }

    let circlePoint = map.convert(startPoint, toPointTo: map) // circle center in View coordinate system

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        let point = sender.location(in: map)
        // Set touch radius in points (20), not meters to support different map zoom levels
        if point.radiusContainsPoint(radius: 20, point: circlePoint) {
            // set class property to store initial circle position before start dragging
            initialDragPoint = circlePoint
            map.isScrollEnabled = false
            isDragEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            map.isScrollEnabled = true
            isDragEnabled = false
        }
    case .changed:
        if isDragEnabled {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: map)
            let newPoint = CGPoint(x: initialDragPoint.x + translation.x, y: initialDragPoint.y + translation.y)
            let updatedCoordinate = map.convert(newPoint, toCoordinateFrom: map)
            let newOverlay = makeCircleOverlay(at: updatedCoordinate)
            map.remove(circleOverlay)
            map.add(newOverlay)
            circleOverlay = newOverlay
        }
    case .ended, .failed, .cancelled:
        map.isScrollEnabled = true
        isDragEnabled = false
    case .possible:
        break
    }
}

// MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```