# Resizing MKCircle on MKMapView is flickering

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I'm trying to solve a problem since few days and I've got no good results. I've got a point and a circle on `MKMapView`. I've got `UISlider` and want to change size of `MKCircle`. Size is changed but during resizing this circle flickers and blinks.

Here is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    Annotation *_annotation;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    [_annotation setCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0)];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:_annotation];
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:_annotation.coordinate animated:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(_annotation.coordinate, 1000, 1000);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region];

    [self _addCircleOnCurrentLocationWithRadius:_slider.value];
}

- (IBAction)onSliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    [self.mapView removeOverlays:self.mapView.overlays];
    [self _addCircleOnCurrentLocationWithRadius:sender.value];
}

- (void)_addCircleOnCurrentLocationWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:_annotation.coordinate radius:radius];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:circle level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Annotation"];
    return view;
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKCircleView *view = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];
    view.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    view.alpha = 0.3;
    return view;
}

@end
```

I've tried:

- removing old overlays and adding new one,
- doing as above with `NSOperationQueue`

Here is [a screen recording how it looks like](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11493275/stackoverflow/flickering.mov).

I see that is possible to do, Apple did this in Reminders app.

Also I'm familiar with following topics:

- [Smooth resizing of MKCircle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571332/smooth-resizing-of-mkcircle)
- [Moving MKCircle on MKMapview and dragging MKMapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441059/moving-mkcircle-on-mkmapview-and-dragging-mkmapview)
- [Smooth resizing of MKCircle](http://www.coderexception.com/CmbNBH63UyxyUXXP/smooth-resizing-of-mkcircle)

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**
I've did it. I will add an answer with class which supports resizing today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've did it by creating subclass of MKCircleView and override `- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` method. [TSCircleView class is shared on github here.](https://github.com/tomkowz/TSCircleView).